# How to convert html string(or file) to pdf file using wkhtmltopdf c library- steps?

Tags: html, c++, pdf

I am looking for a c/c++ library which can be used to convert html string/file into pdf. Researching StackOverflow led me to wkhtmltopdf c library. I download the zip from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html. When I run wkhtmltopdf using command line it works fine and converts the HTML file into pdf output file. But my requirement is to convert HTML file or html string(preferably) into pdf file programmatically from a C++ program. I do not want to use it as command line(or mimic it using say UNIX like "system" command). I am using Windows OS. Could anyone please help me how do I achieve it using wkhtmltopdf. Thank you in advance.
[image]